# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, pandas

I created a data frame using the following line:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/cs213/Desktop/class1.csv', sep = ',', error_bad_lines=False)
```

and if print the columns as such

```
print (df.columns)
```

I get

> Index(['Text', 'label'], dtype='object')

But if I wanted to use the columns as in here

```
df = df[df.Text.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
df = df[df.Text.apply(lambda x: x !="")]
df = df[df.label.apply(lambda x: x !="")]
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label'

I have already tried the solution in here: 
[Data-frame Object has no Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38134643/7631183) 
and it did not work.

Sample of the CSV 
 [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QzT_RxhoD3pNdW0vUI6qcJz9L7PsaKCW)

Here is the output of df.head()
[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample of your csv?

Comment: Give a reproducible sample of the data

Comment: @pissall I added it

Comment: Looks like if a column is named 'labels', `df.labels` returns the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'labels'` but `df['labels']` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 1:

Reproducible sample of your CSV :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': [u'Well I am', u"Not my scene", u"Brutal"], 'label': ['y', 'n', 'n']})
```

The function you are trying to run:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': [u'Well I am', u"Not my scene", u"Brutal"], 'label': ['y', 'n', 'n']})
>>> df
           Text label
0     Well I am     y
1  Not my scene     n
2        Brutal     n
>>> df = df[df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Text, label]
Index: []
```

Of course there will be no attribute 'label'

So what's happening is that, all `x.isnumeric()` calls return `False`, and hence none of the data is saved to `df`. What you are trying to do with `df = df[df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]` is that "In df, what are the rows in which 'Text' is numeric." (Now this returns `False`). None of the rows are numeric, so you get an empty dataframe.

Comment: I am still getting an error, KeyError: 'Text', KeyError: 'Text', KeyError: 'label'

Comment: Show the output of your df.head()

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it, what's wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Updated @user7631183