# AttrributeError with dataframe when processing google locations json data

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to process a JSON file containing google location history data and am trying to put all the data points into a dataframe. I am using this code as reference (https://github.com/nurkiewicz/google-location-history/blob/master/Google%20location%20history.ipynb). However, I encounter this error:

return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'locations'

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gp
import shapely.geometry as sg
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
   

def parse_json(json):
    points = [sg.Point(xy) for xy in zip(json.locations.apply(lambda x: x["longitudeE7"] / 10000000),
                                     json.locations.apply(lambda x: x["latitudeE7"] / 10000000))]
    df = gp.GeoDataFrame(geometry=points)
    return df

df = parse_json(pd.read_json("2022_MAY.json"))
```

This is what the location history looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts9cE.png)

I'm still new to Python so I'm unsure how to resolve this issue?

I tried debugging the code to go through the json but wasn't really sure what was going wrong.

Comment: When asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). That said, it’s clear the issue is just that you don’t have a column in the data called “locations”. The match must be exact, so it could be a capitalization issue. Check your data and make sure to use the actual column name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134643/how-to-resolve-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: The JSON sample that you showed (via image) does not contain a member called "locations".

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand now. I think my json was different than the one used in my reference and did not contain the "locations" member so I replaced that and it fixes the issue. Thank you for the help!